# No graphics acceleration with an Nvidia GeForce 8500 GT

Tags: 11.10, drivers, nvidia

Brand new installation of Ubuntu 11.10 and then install the nvidia proprietary driver (280.13) by selecting "Additional Drivers" -> driver activated and used (according to the same menu).
When I type "glxinfo" in a terminal I get this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
Major opcode of failed request:  137 (NV-GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  4 ()
Resource id in failed request:  0x5400003
Serial number of failed request:  32
Current serial number in output stream:  32
```

"lspci | grep VGA" gives:

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation G86 [GeForce 8500 GT] (rev a1)
```

Before this  upgrade I was on a 11.04 perfectly functional and fluids with 3D effects ... Also, I work with dual screen (configured with nvidia-settings) and when I select the menu "glx information" nvidia-settings crash ... I don't understand these errors because my environment was functional prior to "clean" installation...

Do you have any ideas ? People in the same situation?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Much the same thing just happened to me (running 10.04) after the most recent Ubuntu kernel update.  I looked at glxinfo after seeing the same xsettings crash.

I did the following:

1. change to a terminal;
2. `sudo service gdm stop`
3. `sudo apt-get remove nvidia*`
4. `./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-285.05.09.run` to run the installer - I did not choose to add the 32-bit compatibility stuff on my 64 bit machine this time - there were a bunch of warnings about directories not existing;
5. `sudo service gdm start`
6. log in normally;
7. go to 'Preferences:Appearances:Visual Effects' and select 'Extra' - it worked this time;
8. re-import Compiz settings; and I am good to go again - until the next kernel update?

But after doing the above, when I rebooted I came up in low-graphics safe mode. Trying to run the nvidia-xconfig or nvidia-installer (I forget which), it complained that the 'nouveau' drivers were installed, and asked if I wanted to have the program try to disable that by inserting a file in `/etc/modprobe.d/` .  I agreed. After rebooting, everything came up great so all's well.

Comment: Following some additional rummaging around, I resorted to the following:

Comment: I did the following: 1.  change to a terminal; 2. 'sudo service gdm stop'; 3. 'sudo apt-get remove nvidia*; 4. './NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-285.05.09.run' to run the installer - I did not choose to add the 32-bit compatibility stuff on my 64 bit machine this time - there were a bunch of warnings about directories not existing; 6. 'sudo service gdm start'; 7. log in normally; 8. go to 'Preferences:Appearances:Visual Effects' and select 'Extra' - it worked this time; 9. re-import Compiz settings; and I am good to go again - until the next kernel update? :P

Comment: Argh.  After doing the above, when I rebooted I came up in low-graphics safe mode.  Trying to run the nvidia-xconfig or nvidia-installer (I forget which) it complained that the 'nouveau' drivers were installed, and asked if I wanted to have the program try to disable that by inserting a file in /etc/modprobe.d/.  I agreed.  After rebooting, everything came up great so all's well.

Comment: Gary, I've added your comments to your answer.